# Html Multiple Input Elements With Same Name

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I came across a specific and interesting problem yesterday. Assume we have the following html code block:

```
<div id="addresses">
 <input type="text" name="address" id="addr1" />
 <input type="text" name="address" id="addr2" />
 <input type="text" name="address" id="addr3" />
</div>
```

While posting this form, input elements that have the same name are joined and values are separated with comma character. For example if we have the values like:

```
addr1 = 'TEST TEST XXX'
addr2 = 'YYY ZZZ 11111'
addr3 = 'ZZZ KKK TEST '
```

submitted form post data is as follows:

```
address = 'TEST TEST XXX', 'YYY ZZZ 11111', 'ZZZ KKK TEST '
```

then i can get each of these values as elements of an array on the server side (3 different elements of array). But if the values are like:

```
addr1 = 'TEST, TEST XXX'
addr2 = 'YYY ZZZ, 11111'
addr3 = 'ZZZ KKK, TEST '
```

then submitted form data becomes:

```
address = 'TEST, TEST XXX', 'YYY ZZZ, 11111', 'ZZZ KKK, TEST '
```

then the resulting array contains 6 elements which is totally wrong. I believe COMMA character which is contained in the value is not escaped.

Any ideas on this issue. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this HTML

```
<div id="addresses">
    <form:input path="address[0]"  />
    <form:input path="address[1]"  />
    <form:input path="address[2]"  />
</div>
```

and Spring should populate your input texts with the values of the `String[] address` server-side object and vice-versa.

You can take a look here: http://bitbybitblog.com/forms-and-data-models-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: I ended up changing input names into unique values by adding index value to each input name (ie. address_1,address_2).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using an array.

Change each input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="address[]" id="addr1" />
```

and when you will fetch the data you will have an array without any issue about comma or else.

```
$_POST['adddess']=array(0=>'TEST, TEST XXX',1=>'YYY ZZZ, 11111',2=>'ZZZ KKK, TEST ');
```

and you can access each item based on the index

Comment: I am not using PHP on the server side. I am using Java - Spring MVC. What i am asking is a generic / server technology agnostic way of solution. Maybe changing delimiter (comma) character or maybe escaping the delimiter character.

Comment: you didn't post the language you use in your question. Edited it. Anyway I think you will be able to turn the second part of the answer in the JAVA way of getting posted values

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple input fields with one NAME attribute value, use unique values. That can make your code much more robust.

```
<div id="addresses">
 <input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" />
 <input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" />
 <input type="text" name="addr3" id="addr3" />
</div>
```

On the php side:

```
<?php
$address = array($_REQUEST['addr1'], $_REQUEST['addr2'], $_REQUEST['addr3']);
?>
```

Comment: I am not using PHP on the server side. I am using Java - Spring MVC. What i am asking is a generic / server technology agnostic way of solution. Maybe changing delimiter (comma) character or maybe escaping the delimiter character.

Comment: Then indeed change the delimiter if that is possible in your situation.