# How to get data from tapestry textfield with the same name?

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

I am so new using tapestry,
i got several problem using it, how to get value from tapestry textfield with the same name?

For example:

```
<t:form t:id="names">
    <t:errors/>
    <div class="input-box">
        <t:textfield type="text" name="birthdate[Day]"/>
        <t:textfield type="text" name="birthdate[Month]"/>
        <t:textfield type="text"  name="birthdate[Year]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" name="proceed" class="btn" value="Proceed" />
        </div>
    </div>
</t:form>
```

I try fill it with birthdate[Day] = 20, birthdate[Month] = 08, birthdate[Year] = 1992, and just debug it on backend like this:

```
@Property
@Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
private List<String> birthdate;

Object onSuccess() {
    logger.info("data birthdate:            "+birthdate);  // print null
    logger.info("data birthdate toString:   "+birthdate.toString());  // print null
    logger.info("data birthdate 0:          "+birthdate.get(0));  // print null

    return null;
}
```

All of them only returned null..

How to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you have a List<String> birthdate; rather than 3 fields to capture the the values of 3 different text fields? Or why are you not using DateField?

Comment: DateField is not customizable, my apps using another 3rd party date picker.. and about 3 fields, i can't do that because my frontend dev keep requesting me building inputs like that (3 input 1 name)... so is this the con of using tapestry?

Comment: Sure you can leave the name same but, you need to specify the `t:id` which is used to map the value from `Names.tml` to the `Names.java` POJO.

Comment: there was a map.. `<t:textfield type="text" name="birthdate[Day]"/>` to `private List<String> birthdate;`. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370754/2647910 look at the comment i think he got difficulties too

Comment: There is a mix of tapestry and spring ... I only used tapestry in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from a Spring and Hibernate era, `Tapestry` feels weird. Based on my 10 minutes of reading you are not mapping fields properly and missing a few things such as

- You are not using `t:id`
- You have 3 text fields in your `.tml` and then a list in your `.java` not sure what you are planning to do there

As an example I did something as follow `Names.java`

```
package com.raf.test.pages;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.tapestry5.PersistenceConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Persist;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Names {
    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String birthDay;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String birthMonth;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String birthYear;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String aDate;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private String monthAndYear;

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private Date actualDateField;

    Object onSuccess() {
       logger.info("birthDay: " + birthDay);
       logger.info("birthMonth: " + birthMonth);
       logger.info("birthYear: " + birthYear);

       if(aDate != null && !aDate.isEmpty()) {
           String[] chunks = aDate.split("-");
           if(chunks.length > 2) {
               logger.info("aDate [Year]: " + chunks[0]);
               logger.info("aDate [Month]: " + chunks[1]);
               logger.info("aDate [Day]: " + chunks[2]);
           }
       }

       logger.info("monthAndYear: " + monthAndYear);

       logger.info("actualDateField: " + actualDateField);

       return null;
    }
}
```

and the `Names.tml` as follow

```
<html t:type="layout" title="test com.example"
      xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

<t:form t:id="names">
    <t:errors/>
    <div class="input-box">
        <t:textfield type="text" name="birthdate[Day]" placeholder="birthdate[Day]" t:id="birthDay"/>
        <t:textfield type="text" name="birthdate[Month]" placeholder="birthdate[Month]" t:id="birthMonth"/>
        <t:textfield type="text"  name="birthdate[Year]" placeholder="birthdate[Year]" t:id="birthYear"/>
        <!-- Uses html5 date type-->
        <t:textfield type="date"  name="normladate" placeholder="Normal date" t:id="aDate"/>

        <!-- Uses html5 month -->
        <t:textfield type="month"  name="justmonth" placeholder="Month Year" t:id="monthAndYear"/>

        <!-- Actual date field -->
        <t:datefield  name="actualDateField" placeholder="Actual date" t:id="actualDateField"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" name="proceed" class="btn" value="Proceed" />
        </div>
    </div>
</t:form>
</html>
```

And here is sample output in eclipse

```
[INFO] pages.Names birthDay: bb
[INFO] pages.Names birthMonth: aa
[INFO] pages.Names birthYear: 2nineteen
[INFO] pages.Names aDate [Year]: 2018
[INFO] pages.Names aDate [Month]: 02
[INFO] pages.Names aDate [Day]: 18
[INFO] pages.Names monthAndYear: 2018-02
[INFO] pages.Names actualDateField: Fri Feb 16 00:00:00 EST 2018
```

As you can see each field in `Names.tml` is mapped to corresponding field in `Names.java` POJO.

Comment: `You are not using t:id` i don't know..but adding t:id is not working here.. still null.. `You have 3 text fields in your .tml and then a list in your .java` i was thingking that list could catch input with the same name..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're thinking that Tapestry's TextField is the *same thing* as an HTML "input type=text" HTML element. It isn't. TextField is a Tapestry component that *outputs* an "input type=text" HTML element, but it identifies the object being edited using the "value" parameter, not "name", as described in the docs: http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/TextField.html

I offer 3 possible approaches:

1) If possible, don't use a 3-element List for the date parts. That's just going to make everything harder and messier. Instead, have a separate property for each, called birthDay, birthMonth and birthYear:

```
@Property
@Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
private String birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear;
```

with the following in your template:

```
<t:textfield t:id="birthDay" value="birthDay"/>
<t:textfield t:id="birthMonth" value="birthMonth"/>
<t:textfield t:id="birthYear" value="birthYear"/>
```

or use the following in your template, which is equivalent (because Tapestry uses looks for a property matching the t:id paramter if it doesn't find a value parameter) and much cleaner:

```
<t:textfield t:id="birthDay"/>
<t:textfield t:id="birthMonth"/>
<t:textfield t:id="birthYear"/>
```

2) Alternatively, if you really want to make your web designer happy by using the same "name" attribute for each field, you could write it like this, equivalently:

```
<input type="text" t:type="textfield t:id="birthDay" name="birthday"/>
<input type="text" t:type="textfield t:id="birthMonth" name="birthday"/>
<input type="text" t:type="textfield t:id="birthYear" name="birthday"/>
```

(If you do add a "name" parameter on a Tapestry component then its value will be ignored and will *not* appear in the resulting HTML. Instead, the HTML that the TextField emits (generally) includes a name attribute whose value matches the t:id attribute.)

3) Lastly, you *could* skip the TextField component entirely and just use plain old HTML form elements with your 3-element list of strings:

```
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="${birthdate.get(0)}"/>
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="${birthdate.get(1)}"/>
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="${birthdate.get(2)}"/>
```

Then you could retrieve the submitted values using:

```
@Inject
private Request request;
...
String[] birthDateParts = request.getParameters("birthday");
birthdate = Arrays.asList(birthDateParts);
```

That's awkward. And you lose all of Tapestry's helpful validation and error reporting features, and you have to manage all the details yourself. So I don't recommend that route.

Comment: how the world `<t:textfield t:id="birthDay" value="birthdate[Day]"/>` this gonna work? yes i am so new in tapestry.. i will try that code tomorrow morning..

Comment: You're right, that birthdate[Day] syntax won't work. I carelessly copied that from your question. I've rewritten my answer. Let me know if it makes more sense now.