# Request does not return all data from the form

Tags: php, html

I have a section in which a user can add input values and can add an input field as many as he/she wants. the first input field is default added to the DOM.

The form looks like this

[image]

Here is HTML for this form assume user added one input field

```
<dvi class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card mt-5 col-md-12 animated bounceInDown myForm" id="multiple-container">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4>Bidders Information</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" id="add_info">

                <div id="dynamic_container">
                    <small id="bidder">Bidder 1</small>
                    <span class="bmd-form-group"><div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </span>
            <span class="bmd-form-group"><div class="input-group mt-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="atribute name" name="params_name" id="field1" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" placeholder="atribute value" name="params_value" id="field2" class="form-control">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm moreinput_field" id="add_more_input">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    </span>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body" id="add_info0">

        <div id="dynamic_container">
            <small id="bidder">Bidder 2</small>
            <span class="bmd-form-group"><div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </span>
    <span class="bmd-form-group"><div class="input-group mt-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="atribute name" name="params_name" id="field1" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" placeholder="atribute value" name="params_value" id="field2" class="form-control">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm more_input moreinput_field" id="add_more_input0">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
    </span>
    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="remove-more"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" id="card-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add<div class="ripple-container"></div></a>

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right submit_btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</dvi>
```

On my controller, I have this.

```
   public function store(Request $request){

            dd($request);
    }
```

Which return me the following

[image]

as you can see it return only the second input fields

What is wrong with my code???

Comment: Have you try `$request->all();` ?

Comment: `</dvi>` ?? should be `</div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html Multiple Input Elements With Same Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368891/html-multiple-input-elements-with-same-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell laravel that it's a collection of names for example this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name" class="form-control">
```

Should be like this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name[]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: nothing to do with laravel or collections, you need to send the variable as array in your request.

Comment: @N69S I said _you have to tell lararavel_ i am not saying that's it's related to laravel :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting only 1 value is because your HTML attributes have the same `name`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name" class="form-control">
```

In the above the `name` attribute is `bidder_name` which will be same for both the rows. So you are only getting the 2nd Row.

You can change it like below

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name[]" class="form-control">
```

Same changes needs to be made for other 2 HTML Form Elements.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with laravel specifically, that's how HTTP requests work.
The two inputs have the same `name` parameter so the second one overwrite the first one.

If you want multiple values in the same variable, use it as a table by adding brackets.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="variable_name[]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: *Technically* it's PHP rather than HTTP if you want to be nitpicky... the URL/Request might have something like `?var=1&var=2&var=3` - PHP will only *read* `var=3` (each `var` overwrites the previous) whereas Perl/CGI will treat it as an array and get (the equivalent of) `var = [1,2,3]` - adding the `[]` to the variable names makes PHP work like Perl in this respect.

Comment: @CD001 technically, it's a HTTP request not PHP Request. Take time to check the HTTP protocol (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). It's the same request if you use PHP/JAVA/C/JS/ASP in the server side. Browsers doesnt know what type is your code. if you inspect the request in your browser, you will see that it is overwriting the values .

Comment: I know it's an HTTP Request - that's not what I'm saying - the HTTP Request body will happily contain all the vars, e.g. `var=1&var=2&var=3` even if the vars all have the same name... **however** PHP on the server treats the Request body differently to Perl/CGI. PHP will only read `var=3` in this case (each `var` overwrites the previous) whereas Perl will treat multiple instances of the same variable as an array; in short `var[]=1&var[]=2&var[]=3` is required to make **PHP** treat the variables as an array... it's **not** required for Perl/CGI.

Comment: @CD001 I know but if you read the RFC, you would see that PHP behavior is the standard.it's not only PHP who is following it. peal/CGI is not following standard. Furthermore, you can get the whole body as raw input with `php://input` so it's not like preventing it.

Comment: Ahh - I see what you mean... I didn't think *how* multiple instances of the same variable *should* be treated was actually defined in the RFC spec - I thought it was left up to the processing software (PHP, Perl, whatever) to decide how to deal with it.

Comment: ... finally found it, it was defined in RFC 7578 5.2 - *"Form parts with identical field names MUST NOT be coalesced."* - defined in July 2015, prior to which (according to appendix A.) handling of multiple fields with the same name wasn't defined (so the last time I used Perl/CGI it hadn't been defined). If I''m going to be wrong, I'm going to do the research to find out exactly where I'm wrong! :D (it would have bugged me if I hadn't been able to find it)

Comment: @CD001 as the internet evolved, and now we commonly send form inputs using the json format, W3C has submitted specs that covers posting arrays. https://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion, you can also defined bidder id inside the array something like:

`name="bidder_name[b1]"` or just `name="bidder_name[1]"`

This will help you to understand which index related to which bidder where you have multiple bidder.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name[b1]" class="form-control">
```

or

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidder_name[1]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Hi bro can you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459500/store-function-not-saving-data-to-the-database