# store function not saving data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a form in which a user can enter different data, the form contains two parts.

[image]

First part data will be saved to a table named `pages`(works perfect), the second part data will be saved to the table named `parameters` the table `parameters` contain a column which holds repeated data-name(not working),

Here is how table should look.

[image]

I have created a `PIVOT table` for `paramaters` and `prebids` table like this.

prebid_parameter,

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prebid_parameter', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('prebid_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('prebid_id')->references('id')->on('prebids');
        $table->bigInteger('parameter_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('parameter_id')->references('id')->on('parameters');
    });
}
```

And page_prebid like this.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('page_prebid', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('page_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('page_id')->references('id')->on('pages');
        $table->bigInteger('prebid_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('prebid_id')->references('id')->on('prebids');

    });
}
```

And I have created relationships like this.

Page model.

```
class Page extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
        "title",
        "articles",
        "status"
    ];
    public function prebids(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prebid');
    }
}
```

Prebid model.

```
class Prebid extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =["bidders_name"];

    public function parameters(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parameter');
    }
    public function pages(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Page');
    }
}
```

And Parameter Model looks like this.

```
class Parameter extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =[
        "params_name",
        "params_value",
        "bidders_name"
    ];
    public function prebids(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prebid');
    }
}
```

And finanlly I have page controller store function to save the data like this.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $page = Page::create([
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'articles' => $request->get('articles'),
            'status' => $request->get('status'),
        ]);

        $page->save();

        $page->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
        $page->prebids()->sync($request->prebids, false);

        return redirect("/pages")->with("sucess", "data saved");
    }
```

When I add `dd($request)` in-store function I get the following

[image]

`Note: parameter and prebid controllers are just empty`

Now when I click the submit button only the first part data is saved to database, the rest are not saved to the database.

Here is repo : [demo](https://github.com/throne1986/roayalad-blog)

What am I doing wrong with my code? am new to laravel though.

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prebids');` is that a typo? because the model is named `Prebid`

Comment: @Saly3301 yep was typo my bad, but still the same

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: @devpro no am still trying to solve it :(

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things are jumping out.  I don't see an actual relationship for `tags` in the model you have displayed.  Do you have a relationship on **Page** for `tags`?

Also, this line:

```
$page->prebids()->sync($request->prebids, false);
```

is looking for the input from request for `prebids` but I'm not seeing that in your request object.  I see `params_value`, which would not be sent to the sync() method.
And thus, not be synced.

Give this a try:

```
$page->prebids()->sync($request->params_value, false);
```

Comment: Yes, I will send you repository , u can check out it will be much simple, wait a second

Comment: Here is repo https://github.com/throne1986/roayalad-blog you can check what am I doing wrong

Comment: Yes, I can see `tags()` on the **Page** model on the repo.  But I can't see where you are sending `prebids`.  I looked at resources/views/pages/create.blade.php and it looks like it is sending `params_value`.  Did you give a try with the last line of my answer?

Comment: Changing to what u have suggested , now I am getting this `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`page_prebid`, CONSTRAINT `page_prebid_prebid_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`prebid_id`) REFERENCES `prebids` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `page_prebid` (`page_id`, `prebid_id`) values (7, eee)) `

Comment: OK, that's good.  It means we've solved the original problem.  You were referencing the wrong key from the `$request` object.  The second issue is that your form is not set up correctly (I think) - It looks like you probably don't have the `id=>name` pair set up on the form?  Therefore `$request` is only returning the name, not the id from your prebid.  Your form is sending as type TEXT.  To make a multi-relation work, you need a SELECT with the ID to match.  You need to re-work your form and your create method to send the data to that form. But that's a different question :)

Comment: But now we are sending only `params_value `while in the form I have 3 parameters `params_name`, `params_value`, and `bidders_name` , ?

Comment: Yes, you need to re-work your form.  You need a `select` for those that have multiple `ids`.  If you are sending other fields like `params_name`, you need to have the code on your controller to catch these and add them.  For this question, you need to re-work the incoming `sync` to catch the correct `request` var, whatever that may be.  Your next problem, though is going to take some work - you need to figure out how you want to handle the various incoming fields b/c right now those fields are not aligned to `store()`.  Maybe think through the architecture and ask another question on that.

Comment: On which controller ? Parameter? Prebid? Or Page?